# Opencart order list admin controller

Tags: opencart

I have the admin > view > tamplate > sale > order_list.tpl which I assume is handled by admin > controller > sale > order.php . More specific, getList() method. However when i edit this method, nothing changes in the frontend and I can't figure out why. I assume it's the wrong controller... Any ideas? I'm new to opencart.

Comment: what code exactly are you editing?  is it possible that you have a vqmod or ocmod overriding your changes?

Answer (score 0):

The selected controller seems to be the right one.Just put some exit;or die(); and check.